# WIX Toolset Bundle does not detect package that was just installed

Tags: wix3.5, bootstrapper

I am creating a super simple bootstrapper project that installs just 1 MSI.

Install works perfectly, but when I do an uninstall from (ARP), the package just installed is not detected, so it is not removed, but the bootstrapper is removed from ARP, making it seem like the product is gone.

I have to run the EXE again, which makes it seem like an install is happening, but when the MSI is executed, it shows the options to change or remove the product (as is expected).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
 xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

<Bundle Name="Bed Occupancy Monitoring"
      Version="$(var.PRODUCTVERSION)"
      Manufacturer=""
      UpgradeCode="4346DC9B-5B4D-4301-A8A6-EE4ED4C001DB">

<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
    LicenseUrl=""
    ThemeFile="HyperlinkLargeTheme.xml"
    LocalizationFile="HyperlinkTheme.wxl"
    LogoFile="Logo.png"
    SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
    ShowVersion="yes"/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

<Chain>
  <MsiPackage Id="BedOccupancy"
              SourceFile="$(var.Installer.TargetPath)"
              DisplayName="Bed Occupancy $(var.PRODUCTVERSION)"
              DisplayInternalUI="yes"
              Permanent="no"
              Visible="no"/>
</Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: A bundle log file for the uninstall should explain what is going on. To find the log file see: https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912407-Create-a-log-file-

Comment: I have looked at the log files - it always shows that the Detect Package did not detect the actual package that was literally just installed.  This is happening on 3 other bootstrap projects.  Only 1 project is ever detected by the bundle process.